# Locate a file with specific words in the path, but also a specific file name

Tags: bash, find, locate

I want to search both the path and file names for words, and then get their size.

Using locate gets me all of the files I want but not their size:

```
locate -A wordlist oracle

/usr/share/dirb/wordlists/vulns/oracle.txt
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/data/wordlists/hci_oracle_passwords.csv
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/data/wordlists/oracle_default_hashes.txt
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/data/wordlists/oracle_default_passwords.csv
/usr/share/metasploit-framework/data/wordlists/oracle_default_userpass.txt
/usr/share/sparta/wordlists/oracle-default-userpass.txt
/usr/share/wfuzz/wordlist/vulns/oracle9i.txt
```

Using Find, I can search for file names, and get their size like so;

```
find /usr/share/ -name '*oracle*' -exec ls -lh {} \;
```

However, this finds more then I want. How do I filter **find** such that the path (or file) has the word "wordlist" in it? Or if thats not possible how do I pipe/feed/automate getting the size of the locate results?

Comment: Have you tried `find /usr/share/ -name '*wordlist*/*oracle*' -exec ls -lh {} \;`?

Comment: @AndrewShum unfortunately `find -name` doesn't work like that (as it will tell you if you try: *Unix filenames usually don't contain slashes...*). However you could try `find /usr/share -path '*wordlist*' -name '*oracle*'` or even `-path '*wordlist*/*oracle*'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls -ldh `locate -A wordlist oracle`
```

or

```
ls -ldh $(locate -A wordlist oracle)
```

I added the d option in ls to take care of folders (if any).

Comment: Using backticks is discouraged, as they aren't nestable, and, depending on the font, harder to identify than the preferred $(...) construct.